# How to disable jquery when opened on an iphone

Tags: jquery

I would like to disable Ascensor.js when the website is opened on an iphone?

I have tried this so far, but it doesnt seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      if($(screen).height() > 330) {
      $('#main', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}  
});
```

or does anyone know how to get ascensor to work properly on an iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Well, couldn't you add that part to the backend side? Check for the user-agent, and if it belongs to an iPhone, do not add the `<script type="text/javascript" src="Ascensor.js"/>`

Another option would be this:

```
    if($(screen).height() > 330) {
          $('#main', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');


    }

    else {
        var script = $("<script />");
        script.attr("type", "text/javascript");
        script.attr("src", "js/Ascensor.js");
        $("head").append(script);


   }
```

Basically this should add the script element if the condition is not met.

Comment: And if he's using plain HTML?

Comment: then may the lord have mercy on his soul

Comment: There are alot of sites where simple HTML is better. I'm sure you won't write a full mvc site for just portfolio (or would you?)

Comment: @mrjoltcola: jquery is not backend. Maybe saying a client side only app will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to check for iPhone or iPod.

```
function isiPhone(){
    return (
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
    );
}

if(!isiPhone()){
    //Not an iPhone device do your stuff here
}
```